# No puedo cerrar la ventana del programa

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

mi problema radica en que no puedo cerrar la ventana, diciéndome por el mensaje de error: application has been destroyed.
Lo que quería saber es que ¿Cual sería la forma para poder cerrar la ventana, al momento de que el usuario pulsara el botón salir? 
Aún soy un principiante en la programación y las ventanas en python, les adjunto mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *

class Form:
        def __init__(self, master, salir = False):
            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()

        self.elementos = Spinbox(master,from_=1, to = 15)
        self.elementos.place(x = 170, y = 260)
        #Botón de aceptar para leer el número de elementos
        self.aceptarBoton = Button(master,command = self.AceptarBoton, text = "Aceptar")
        self.aceptarBoton.place(x = 220 , y = 300)
        #Botón de salir
        self.salirBoton = Button(master, command = self.SalirBoton, text = "Salir")
        self.salirBoton.place(x = 220, y = 400)
        #Boton de Generar otra contraseña
        self.otractrBoton = Button(master, text = "Generar otra contraseña")
        self.otractrBoton.place(x=170, y=350)


    #Creo objetos para que hagan alguna acción
    def SalirBoton(self):

        self.salir = True
        resultado = self.salir
        return resultado
    def AceptarBoton(self):
        print ("Aun sin hacer la funcion")
root = Tk()
root.title("Generación de contraseñas")
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(500, 500))
a = Form(root)
root.mainloop()
if( a.SalirBoton() == True ):
    root.destroy()
```

Espero puedan ayudarme :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que cuando entras en el `mainloop()` de un `Tk()`, no se va a ejecutar ninguna otra línea después (ya que estás dentro de un loop, internamente, que maneja todas las funciones internas de tkinter).

Lo que debes hacer es controlar el `root` desde la clase (lo guardas como atributo):

```
 def __init__(self, master, salir=False):
        self.master = master
```

Finalmente, en la función `SalirBoton` tendrías:

```
def SalirBoton(self):
        self.master.destroy()
```

En lugar de tener un `if` luego del `mainloop()`.